# Java Akka HTTP request parameter extraction

Tags: java, rest, java-8, akka, akka-http

I would like to create a route with Java and akka for PUT/PATCH requests such as:

```
/item/UUID/{JSON-REPRESENTATION-OF-ITEM}
```

for example:

```
/item/c72d9e07-d5b6-4eb6-8d73-60b4451539f4/{"name":"hello world"}
```

I have tried something like this but the UUID is no longer accessible in the inner route handler:

```
 pathPrefix("item", () ->
                path(PathMatchers.uuidSegment(), (UUID itemId) ->
                        PathMatchers.remaining(), (String json) ->

                        // PATCH        
                        patch(() ->
                            entity(Jackson.unmarshaller(ItemResource.class), item -> {
                                            return updateItem(itemId,item);
                            })
```

(It does not compile because itemId is not accessible anymore when calling updateItem)

I am an akka novice so any help appreciated.

UPDATE: 
I see that the following is possible:

```
path(PathMatchers.uuidSegment().slash(PathMatchers.segment()), (UUID itemId, String json) -> { //complete route here }
```

However the json is not extracted correctly just yet (json="")

Comment: That looks to me like it should compile fine. Please could you include the full compiler error (the first error if there are more than one)?

Comment: @Rich the error is 'could not resolve "itemId" on line ... return updateIt...

Comment: Thanks. I misread the initial code, sorry (I think due to the unusual indentation). Your second version fixes the compile error.